# Outputs of devops agnetless tasks :: invoke rest api

Tags: azure-devops

I have a question and I don't find anything about it in microsoft documents.

I use this agentles job:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/http-rest-api?view=azure-devops

I couldn't find how I can use the output variables of this task without using any code / script for use in another task.

Any help / document would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I think it is impossible.**

The task uses agentless job but that job could not support environment variable. And `Invoke REST API` task did not have the option to output the result variable.

One alternative approach is that you could use agent job with a powershell task(that could invoke rest api) and then use custom variable to get that output variables.

**Otherwise**, there is no function to realize that.